# How to get rid of spaces in email body - php sending mail

Tags: php

I am trying to implement send email function using php. It is working fine. But the problem when I open the email in inbox it has a lot of spaces in front of message. Is there any way to get rid of these spaces.

Do I need to add additional headers for this.

**code:**

```
$to = $email;
$from = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Registration confirmation";
$msg = "message goes here";
$mail = new EMAIL();
$arr = $mail->sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,trim($msg));
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to post code to be able to help you.

Comment: if what @steve said is not working, something is wrong with the EMAIL class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<?php

$msg = trim($msg);
$msg = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $msg);

$arr = $mail->sendEmail($to, $from, $subject, $msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$to = $email;
$from = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Registration confirmation";
$msg = "message goes here";
$mail = new EMAIL();
$arr = $mail->sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $msg));
```

This will remove extra spaces, as well as leading and trailing spaces.